# Carousel Vertical com Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

O *carousel* do Bootstrap trabalha com fotos horizontalizadas. Como faço para o mesmo rodar fotos tiradas com a maquina invertida, isto é, verticalizadas.

Outra: Como faço para as imagens rodarem para a esquerda e direita linearmente apenas com a aproximação do mouse nos ícones laterais das imagens?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que as opções que você quer não sejam configuráveis no carousel do bootstrap até mesmo porque perderia as características do carousel.
 Recomendo o desenvolvimento do slide por você ou procure um que satisfaça as suas necessidades por exemplo [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) ou algo mais robusto.